# swapping id's in JS - this only works one time. Why?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I'm playing around with click events, and I notice that this function works only the first time.  Why is that? How can I make it so that it is possible to continuously swap id's between two elements?

And, would there be a dramatic change in approach if one were to pass id's along among a larger number of elements?

I'm not using jQuery at all.  Thanks.

```js
 window.onload = function() {
 document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   document.getElementById("purpleSquare").id = 'redSquare';
   document.getElementById("redSquare").id ="purpleSquare";
 })
};
```

```css
#redSquare {
 background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
#purpleSquare {
 background-color: purple;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
        <div id="redSquare"></div>

        <div id="purpleSquare"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because after running this code...

```js
document.getElementById("purpleSquare").id = 'redSquare';
```

...there will be two elements with `id="redSquare"`.

Therefore, this will be unreliable:

```js
document.getElementById("redSquare")
```

In [DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) and [DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) the behavior was undefined:

> Behavior is not defined if more than one element has this `ID`.

In [DOM4](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid) the first element will be returned. Therefore, the first time you click it will work because you want to get the first one. But when you click again, you want to get the second one, so it doesn't work.

Instead, you can store the elements in variables before changing their IDs.

```
var el1 = document.getElementById("purpleSquare"),
    el2 = document.getElementById("redSquare");
el1.id = 'redSquare';
el2.id ="purpleSquare";
```

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var el1 = document.getElementById("purpleSquare"),
      el2 = document.getElementById("redSquare");
  el1.id = 'redSquare';
  el2.id ="purpleSquare";
})
```

```css
#redSquare {
  background-color: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
#purpleSquare {
  background-color: purple;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="redSquare"></div>
<div id="purpleSquare"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to switch between the ids like this :

```
 document.getElementById("purpleSquare").id = 'xxxxxx';
 document.getElementById("redSquare").id ="purpleSquare";
 document.getElementById("xxxxxx").id = 'redSquare';
```

That should work. Because if you run this line of code :

```
document.getElementById("redSquare").id ="purpleSquare";
```

without the first :

```
 document.getElementById("purpleSquare").id = 'xxxxxx';
```

you will have two elements with id=**"purpleSquare"**. and that create a problem if you trying to run :

```
 document.getElementById("purpleSquare").id = 'redSquare';
```